# Measure semantic similarity (cosine) between a sentence and a paragraph

Tags: similarity, bert-language-model

I have scraped some paragraphs with their Titles and I want to extract semantic similarity (cosine similarity) between every (Title-Paragraph) and a specific General Title. Image here might help in understanding:
[Challenge.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztjba.png)

General Title is a simple sentence like every paragraph title. Paragraphs are a group of sentences.

What do you think is the best strategy to implement?

Answer (score 0):

**first having an overview of the basis principle of what is a text cosine distance**

Your title is itself a short text, so you will compare the distance between a short text and a long text.

The cosine distance, compares the similarity of 2 vectors. In euclidian space the vector [1,1] as the same angle than [2,2] so they are similar despite they have not the same force.

It this two vector was two texts, the first one could be "a flower." and the second "a flower. a flower".

One can compute the distance between a 2 dimensional space, v[x,y] but the same equations can be used in a 3 dimensional space v[x,y,z], and because the math principle doesn't change with number of dimension, the cosine distance can be applied in a n dimension vector space v[x,y,z...n]

**So the main problem is to transform a text to vectors right ?**

Imagine you have to measure cosine distance for texts that only have 2 possible word : "flower", and "a". If so you can use a 2 dimensional vector where

- flower=[1,0]
- a=[0,1]

so a text with : "a flower" or "flower a" will be noted [1,1]
and a text with "a flower a flower" [2,2]

indeed [2,2] and [1,1] are parallel and coincident in a euclidian space

but there is an angle between "a" and "a flower" if you compute the cosine distance between the two

Now if we have a corpus with 3 word in it "a fruit flower"
you will have a 3 dimensional vector :

1. "flower"=[0,0,1]
2. "fruit"=[0,1,0]
3. "a fruit flower"=[1,1,1]
4. "fruit fruit fruit"=[0,3,0]

if 1 and 2 are titles (flower or fruit) then 1 is closer to 3, and 2 is closer to 4

Now you have it if there is 3000 distinct word in your corpus of text, you will build a 3000 dimension vector space and compute the cosine distance between them

here one of the article that's shows the principle of using vector space for word and how to do so with large vectors.
https://nikoskalikis.medium.com/text-similarity-euclidian-distance-vs-cosine-similarity-3a1167f686a

This was the general idea of word based cosine distance

**Now how to acheive a semantic similarity**

You talk about semantic distance this is not exactly the same.
because "I went to paris" should be very similar to "I had been to London" and slightly different to "I went to school" because paris and london are capital city.

There is also some other algo to adress this issue. Explaining them would take an entire blog article.

One of them is TFIDF but the best of them is world2vec it use the same principle but in a much sophisticated way. Here a general intuition article https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Word2vec there is so much explanation of how it works on internet that I  dont know what source to advise.

TFIDF is easier to implement, since word2vec is NN approach. Here an article that explains and somehow compares the 2 concept https://towardsdatascience.com/word-embedding-techniques-word2vec-and-tf-idf-explained-c5d02e34d08

So the *best strategy to implement* is using word2vec with kereas tensor flow, but it depend on you time, resources, which langages you know or how confortable you are with the concept.

I will share the best advice that a ancient Phd gives to me : "use the any  of the 3 if it dont do the job replace it latter. It's like choosing any engine you like to put in a car, if you want to race it, you first need it to drive at least, then, latter you could change the engine for a better one or improve it."

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have already done some research in tfidf and word2vec but I am about to use a kind of bert model. Something like Sentence Bert. My problem is that these models use sentences as input and not a whole paragraph or a group of sentences. I dont know how to handle paragraphs in those models. I am fluent in python and pytorch.

Comment: I am not sure BERT is the tool suited for that problem wich seems to be a information retrieval problem : the title act as the question, and the paragraph the best rank. BERT seems to be adapted to NSP or sentence focused. So I will go straight to world2vec. Just because BERT  was not designed for processing long spans
of text, thhis goal is hard to achieve. BUT it is possible Yang & al 2019 worked on it and had  good results. https://aclanthology.org/D19-1352.pdf . I dont know what is your context. If it is for rapid production use BERT with lucene and you will have results much faster.

Comment: In other word you will have hard time to adapt BERT to IR problems, it depends, if it is to learn or for pure research goal, or for R&D only. "What do you think is the best strategy to implement?" best for what ? time to market, accuracy, scalability. Since there is no such contextual semantic information in a title, I will still go for word2vec. But doing it with BERT is a big appealling challenge, let me know your result if you compare the 2. Good luck and have fun :)

Comment: My data are papers Titles with their abstracts. My goal is to feed the model a thematic sentence. Based on papers embeddings (Title-Abstract) and sentence embedding, I want to find cosine similarity between papers and the thematic sentence. I read that bert input can accept input up to  512 tokens. I believe that my abstracs have less than this upper bound. I ll let you know if any legit result occur :)

Comment: Ok have a look on that paper this is exactly what you need https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.10084.pdf  but take the conclusion of the paper to account in the state of the art "We showed that BERT out-of-the-box maps sentences to a vector space that is rather unsuitable to be used with common similarity measures
like cosine-similarity. The performance for seven
STS tasks was below the performance of average
GloVe embeddings."

Comment: Ok, very interesting paper. I ll check it. Thank you again.